# Issue with password_hash and password_verify, always returning true in one case, false in another

Tags: php, password-hash

I'm using password_hash to secure password in database, but when I use password_verify, it doesn't match. In the fist case, I use password_verify for the connection of the user, and it always return true, even when it's not the good password. In the second case, I use password_verify when the user wants to change his password, he is asked to give his actual password to change it. In this case, it always return false, even if I use password_verify in the same way I do for the connection.

In my database, password is stored as VARCHAR(60). I also tried VARCHAR(255), makes no difference.

Here is how I use password_hash when user create his account :

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['psw-confirmation'])) {

        $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
        $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
        $pswConfirmation = htmlspecialchars($_POST['psw-confirmation']);

        if($password == $pswConfirmation) {

            // Connection to database
            require('database-connection.php');

            $request = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username");
            $request->execute(array(
                ":username" => $username
            ));
            $return = $request->fetch();

            // If the username doesn't exist yet in the database
            if(!$return) {
                $request->closeCursor();

                $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

                $addProfile = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username, password) VALUES(:username, :password)");
                $addProfile->execute(array(
                    ":username" => $username,
                    ":password" => $hash
                ));
```

I guess this part is working well because I do have a hashed password in my database : `$2y$10$AFV2zouzirBhS30tCCRx9uyZDNMGSJWffUbXMO876T/9nJ8UDQJRi`

Here is how I verify the password for the connection :

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

        $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
        $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);

        // Connection to database
        require('database-connection.php');

        $request = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username");
        $request->execute(array(
            ":username" => $username
        ));
        $return = $request->fetch();
        $hash = $return['password'];

        // If the username exists in the database
        if($return) {

            // And if the password match            
            if(password_verify($password, $hash)) { 
                echo "connected";
            }
```

And here how I verify the password when the user want to change his password : 
if(isset($_POST['actual-psw']) && isset($_POST['new-psw']) && isset($_POST['confirm-psw'])) {

```
        $actualPsw = htmlspecialchars($_POST['actual-psw']);
        $newPsw = htmlspecialchars($_POST['new-psw']);
        $confirmPsw = htmlspecialchars($_POST['confirm-psw']);

        // Connection to database
        require('database-connection.php');

        $request = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id");
        $request->execute(array(
            ':id' => $_SESSION['id']
        ));
        $return = $request->fetch();
        $hash = $return['password'];

        if(password_verify($actualPsw, $hash)) {
            echo "success";
        } else {
            echo "fail";
        }
```

`$_SESSION['id']` is returning the good id of the actual user.

I don't understand why it doesn't work, and it makes me even more confuse that in one case it's always true and in another it's always false, because I used the same way in both cases.

Comment: I'm aware there is a lot of similar questions here, even out of stackoverflow, but none of them fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out where my mistake were;

I had this database-connection.php file :

```
$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'japonwebsite';
$user = 'root';
$password = 'mysql';

try
{
  $database = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $user, 
  $password);
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
  die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

I include this file on all the pages where I need to connect to database, so I have it included on the page to add users to database and the one that verify log in.

Thing is, on both of those pages, I was doing `$password = $_POST['password'];` to stock in a variable the password entered by the user on the sign in or sign up form.

After that, i was doing `include('database-connection.php');` to connect to database. So `$password` was always equal to `mysql`, because I also have a variable `$password` in `database-connection.php`. So I was always adding the hash of "mysql" in the database, and always verifying that the hash in the database was equal to "mysql", so it was always true. I Just renamed the variable $password in database-connection to fix it !